# Raspberry pi with Yocto os sd card is not working with Raspbian os sd card

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, yocto

Few months ago,I built an custom image for Raspberrypi using Yocto Project,flashed it in a sd card and was able to boot raspberrypi.Presently,I am trying to use  a different sd card with raspbian os in same Raspberrypi.But it is not able to boot Raspberrypi.How can I rectify this problem?This is my code which I used few months back to generate yocto image.

```
PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_rpm package_deb"


    EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES ?= "debug-tweaks dbg-pkgs dev-pkgs tools-sdk tools-debug eclipse-debug "


    USER_CLASSES ?= "buildstats image-mklibs image-prelink"




    BB_DISKMON_DIRS ??= "\
        STOPTASKS,${TMPDIR},1G,100K \
        STOPTASKS,${DL_DIR},1G,100K \
        STOPTASKS,${SSTATE_DIR},1G,100K \
        STOPTASKS,/tmp,100M,100K \
        ABORT,${TMPDIR},100M,1K \
        ABORT,${DL_DIR},100M,1K \
        ABORT,${SSTATE_DIR},100M,1K \
        ABORT,/tmp,10M,1K"





    CONF_VERSION = "1"
    MACHINE = "raspberrypi3"
    PREFERRED_VERSION_linux-raspberrypi = "4.%"
    DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = "x11 wayland"
    DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " systemd"
    VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "systemd"
    IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " git apt dpkg opkg rpm sudo wiringpi wiringpi-dev connman connman-client tzdata i2c-tools i2c-tools-dev glibc-utils rpm dhcp-server bluez5 python-smbus bridge-utils hostapd apache2 openvpn iptables nano"
    IMAGE_INSTALL += "wiringpi"
    ENABLE_UART="1"
    ENABLE_SPI_BUS= "1"
    ENABLE_I2C = "1"
```

Comment: Your Yocto stuff is irrelevant and you might as well remove all that stuff from your question. In essence: you can't boot with a Raspbian card. There are many questions: Model Pi, is it a fresh download of Raspbian (which one and from where), Does the power LED stay on? Does the green LED flicker? Please update your question with relevant info. Also search the Internet as this is a question that has been asked many times (`raspberry pi does not boot`).

Comment: ok,after knowing that yocto stuff is irrelevant, I am able to do it.After using diskpart on command prompt.I am able to do it.

Answer (score -1):

ok,after knowing that yocto stuff is irrelevant, I am able to do it.After using diskpart on command prompt.I am able to do it.